# Grouping values by length in a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm doing an exercise. The idea is you have a list inserted with random words. example: `list=["abc","doc","string"]`. What I need to do is group the words by their length in a dictionary in an ascending order with respect to the key so it would appear like this:
`{3: ['abc','doc], 6: ['doc']}`.

This is the code I've done so far. The problem with the code is that if there are two values with the same key, it removes one of them completly, key and value. So this would print: `{3:['abc'], 6:['doc']}`.

```
input = ['abc','doc','string']
length=[]
for a in input:
    x=len(a)
    length.append(x)

input_dict=dict(zip(length,input))
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in sorted(input_dict.items()):
    d[value].append(key)
print(input_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would update your `defaultdict` as follows

```
from collections import defaultdict
words = ['abc','doc','string']
a = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    a[len(word)].append(word)
```

Result

```
>>> a
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: ['abc', 'doc'], 6: ['string']})
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that, I've been at this for a few hours, finally lol. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict 
input_list = ['abc','doc','string']
d = defaultdict(list)
for word in sorted(input_list, key=len):
    d[len(word)].append(word)
```